# Can't load layout file from modules layouts folder

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using the Phil Sturgeon Template Libray within the MX_Controller but I can't load the layout file located inside `/modules/auth/views/layouts/auth_login.php`, views and partials are loaded without problem.

```php
    // *auth_login* is placed in /modules/auth/views/layouts/auth_login.php
    $this->template->set_layout('auth_login')
            ->build('auth/login', $this->data);
```

I'm missing something?

Comment: Instead of calling `$this->template->set_layout...` why not call it like a normal view, like:  `$this->load->view('auth_login');` and then for the content you pass a second paramater i.e. `$this->load->view('auth_login', $this->data);`?

Comment: @Renier you suggest a standard way, it's not my case, I'm using a Template Library and all is working well except I can't load a layout within a modules folder.

Comment: Are you loading the Template Library in the file inside your modules folder?

Comment: Sure, the Template Library is autoloaded.

Comment: Maybe try to load it explicitly for this file? Humor me and try it?

Comment: Just tried and it doesn't work: "Unable to load the requested file: auth_login.php"

Comment: Hmmm... Try using an absolute path? Just ideas on what might be a possible solution...